# ModuleNotFoundError : tkinter in heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, tkinter

I have an application which is using tkinter package for file opening dialog functionality and the application is built on python Django. The application is running absolutely fine in local. But, after deploying in Heroku, I am getting the below error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /
No module named '_tkinter'
Request Method:
GET
Request URL:
http://compare-files.herokuapp.com/
Django Version:
1.11.20
Exception Type:
ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:
No module named '_tkinter'
Exception Location:
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py in <module>, line 36
Python Executable:
/app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version:
3.7.3
Python Path:
['/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python37.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:
Sun, 26 May 2019 14:20:26 +0000
```

The code is:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

    Tk().withdraw()
    file1 = askopenfilename()
    print(file1)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exacly? I'm not an expert of web delepoment, but as far as I know, you cannot open a GUI through the web (or at least, is not easy). Usually the GUI is the webpage itself.

Comment: I am trying to open file through file selection dialog box from the webpage. As I mentioned earlier, the same code is running locally fine, but in Heroku, I am getting the above error.

Comment: Heroku is a remote server. I think your program is trying to open the `tkinter` gui on the screen of the remote server (which does not exist, it's a server). That's why on the server the `tkinter` module is not even installed and you get the `ModuleNotFoundError`. Locally works fine because you have `tkinter` (and a screen) on your machine.

Comment: You can't use tkinter on a web server.

Comment: is there any alternative solution to open file through file dialog box in web in python?

Comment: You should build the file dialog box in the web page. Maybe Django has some ready to use solution, try to search.